# Best practice to merge / not merge svn tags

Tags: svn, svn-merge

I have create a tag named `v1.5` off a branch. After some testing I found some bugs and it seems I have to propagate these changes to `tag/v1.5`. But I see some comments that do not suggest such practice of updating or merging a tag.

My question is what is best way to handle situations like this. Probably delete the tag and recreate it from the branch head revision ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tags, branches, etc. make no sense to Subversion itself, they are just folders and you can do anything you want. However, there are good practices, and tags mean something that you never change. You should have a workflow and stick to that.

For example, we make new developments in the trunk. When it's ready, we create a branch, like 1.5, and then create tags, like 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.5.3, etc. We add bug fixes and create new tags from it, we don't add new features to branches, and we never ever change tags. Then we merge the bugfixes from the branch to trunk when there are new developments. It is a very common workflow.

[Here's a longer article](http://www.boxuk.com/blog/towards-faster-releases/), what I described above is called "stable release model" here, there is a good image to show you what happens where. There are also alternatives and a long discussion. I love those graphs, [here's another one](http://blog.luiscoms.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/svn.png), but it's a bit confusing, arrows shouldn't cross tags, tags should always be a dead end.

Answer (score 1):

the best practice is not to delete `tags` in fact tags are not meant to be touched they are just labels, while its true that everything is a folder in any svn repository, the practice is to usually work on `trunk`, update `branches` in case of bugs, and leave `tags` as markers for previous work history for reference, branches can also be used for separate work, the best practice is to work with a single mainline single trunk pattern and to avoid branches as much as possible (continuous delivery integration) but in your case i would branch fro tag and update it and then merge back to trunk.  `tags` are meant to stay.  what i would do is copy the `tag` into a `branch` with branch name and do the update there.  then I would `merge` it back to `trunk`.  for **automatic merges** there is a cool utility for svn called [automerger utility](https://github.com/liveperson/Auto-Merger)

Google and Facebook adopted trunk based development.   development In the materials above, these Googlers talked about working on HEAD, and that checkins happen to HEAD at all times. Ashish says trunk a few times towards the end in a Q&A section, and he does mention an avoidance of branching for ongoing development (nothing to do with releases per se). So it’s official, Trunk Based Development (TBD) is what Google do, and boy do they scale it! (http://paulhammant.com/2013/05/06/googles-scaled-trunk-based-development/)

Comment: "the best practice is to work with a single mainline single trunk pattern and to avoid branches as much as possible" WTF?! Trunk-only development is BAD IDEA (tm). Branching from tag is also *just delirium*

Comment: Google and Facebook adopted trunk based development so basically you say ... to them.. Also I would recommend using nicer language. development
In the materials above, these Googlers talked about working on HEAD, and that checkins happen to HEAD at all times. Ashish says trunk a few times towards the end in a Q&A section, and he does mention an avoidance of branching for ongoing development (nothing to do with releases per se). So it’s official, Trunk Based Development (TBD) is what Google do, and boy do they scale it!

Answer (score 0):

Tags in SVN is (conventionally) RO subtree. If you have changed after creating tag code, you have to create **new tag** from changed code